# JQuery create a list based on another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I am trying to do is generate an html list based from another list on the page. I have a list along the lines of below:

```
<ul>
  <li class="chosen">content</li>
  <li class="something">content</li>
  <li class="something">content</li>
  <li class="something">content</li>
  <li class="something">content</li>
  <li class="chosen">content</li>
  <li class="chosen">content</li>
</ul>
```

Whats the best plan of action to create a jquery function which will find the list items with the class of "chosen" and create another list with just these.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to clone your list, or just add an empty list under the chosen class list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the li elements with class `chosen`, clone and append into a new `ul` and finally append the `ul` to a container whereever you want or page `body` element.

```
$('<ul />').append($('ul li.chosen').clone()).appendTo(document.body);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TuBjL/1/)**

Comment: Probably mean `<ul/>` there, not `<u/>`. I would edit this but it won't let me because the character difference is less than 6.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! just what I wanted. Ill accept once it allows me.

Comment: Sorry would this be the same with cloning a table with all the table rows with the class "chosen" as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use it on table too.